# Build hermes error on \android\app\build.gradle

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-hermes

I'm having problems installing react native navigation I'm using react 18.1.0 I delete all the navigation packages I've installed and reinstall them, but I'm getting different errors

error

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\reactNative\FirstAppAndroid\android\app\build.gradle' line: 86

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'enableHermes' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================  

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================  

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\reactNative\FirstAppAndroid\android\app\build.gradle' line: 86

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'enableHermes' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================  

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

d\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\reactNative\FirstAppAndroid\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I need to install the screens, stack, drawer, gesture handler, reanimated, safe area context packages, but I removed them because I thought the reason for my errors was the wrong packages I installed.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "FirstAppAndroid",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  }
}
```

it is stated here that there is a problem with buildHermes on line 86

build.gradle

```
 if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    }
```